# Get array keys and values from PHP source

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I'm writing a config editor. I'm reading in the file with fopen and fgets line by line.
I want to get the array keys and values from the string. I'm not familiar with regex thats why i'm asking.

Example config file:

```
$conf['something'] = 'value';
$conf['other_thing']['another_key'] = 3000;
```

I can't loop through the $conf array, as it is a SuperObject in the system, and holds many additional datas, even inited classes...

Comment: as you have a php array why you to to read it again using fopen just include the file and use $conf variable

Comment: why you making your life harder than it could be? Write your config file in more parseable format.

Comment: Why to make the app slower with adding extra parsing? In my case parsing is only needed when config editor is opened in the admin area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\$conf\['(.*?)']\s+=\s+'(.*?)';` here is your pattern. Key is in the group 1 and value is in the group 2.

`$`, `[` and `]` are special characters that's why you should escape them. `\s+` means whitespace characters 1 or more times.

Comment: It would be valid without the whitespace, so I would use `\s*`. The array would also be valid using "key", instead of 'key', so you'd need to account for that. Same goes for value. It's much better just to read this as a PHP array, as mentioned by @t1gor

Comment: ow.. add $ in the end of the pattern (without backslash)

Comment: @shift66 I think the issue is that wintercounter is not using a delimiter, see : http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. By telling him to add the $ to the end are you not causing $ to be the delimiter used? This changes your regex?

Answer (score 2):

I would do smth like this:

```
// get config file as a variable
require_once('config_file.php');

// get keys
$keys = array_keys($conf);

// get config file as a variable
$values = array_values($conf);
```

Comment: If you need to scope that $config variable so that it doesn't infect your actual config variable, then you could wrap a function around the include.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Can you please add an example?

Comment: `class configEditor() { `

`private $conf; `

`function load_config() { `
`include 'config_file.php';`
`$this->conf = $config;`

Comment: It's hard to write in a comment, I was just imagining a case where loading in the config_file.php may override an existing $config variable. You could avert that by loading in a function scope, a little like the code above.

Comment: Tanks, I get it. I was a bit confused as English is not my native and I didn't understand the 'scope' :)

Answer (score 1):

While not direct answer to your question but as you wrote *"I'm writing a config editor."* then I assume you also write this config file down. So assuming your editor keeps config in `$conf` array while it works, I'd just dump it as JSON instead of your PHP code:

```
file_put_contents('config.json', json_encode($conf));
```

and then read it back when needed

```
$conf = json_decode( file_get_contents('config.json') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your regex:

```
\$conf(\[('.*')\])+\s?=\s?(.*);
```

The first matches are your keys, last one your value

Comment: This is probably because the first "\" escapes the string in PHP.

Comment: This example does make some assumptions as to the formatting of the array. It must always have 1 or 0 spaces, so no TABs or multiple spaces should have been added. The key is always designated by a `'` and not ever using `"`. It will also capture the quotes around a value, so that may well need trimming. All-in-all I would consider using the options posted by @t1gor or @WebnetMobile.com

Answer (score 0):

As this is php array you can directly loop through it, and get required key value pairs
else you can you can use php's functions [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) for fetching all keys from the $conf array and [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) for getting array values

or else

if you want to create a config editor try using ini file php has a good support for creating and using config files see this function [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) this is a standard way for creating config file if you have too key value pairs